# How to open individual files or projects with different tabs/spaces setting

Tags: vim, macvim

I use (Mac)Vim in my projects set to use 2 spaces for tabs and even have a script which converts all tabs to 2 spaces on save.

When I work with other developers though, sometimes they use tabs instead of spaces and I am looking for a quick way to switch two different vim configurations, would love to switch them on the command line, like this

```
macvim --oh-no-not-tabs-again .
```

What's the best practice on this?

Comment: There are different ways to approach this depending on your environment.  When you work with other developers, is the tab-style usually all the same for a given directory tree, or do you have to think about it on a file-by-file basis?

Comment: It's on a directory tree basis, basically a whole project with a particular setting. In my case all C# code with tabs, all other web related scripting (Ruby, Javascript) in spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have autocommands fired on a per-directory basis, so you can configure anything you want automatically without hotkeys.  Here's what I came up with:

```
" set up global defaults, these are mine
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set smarttab
set expandtab
set autoindent
set smartindent

" override tab settings on a per-directory basis
function! SetStandardTabs()
  set noexpandtab
  set tabstop=8
  set softtabstop=4
endfunction

augroup PerDirectoryTabs
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufRead,BufEnter,BufNewFile /path/to/csharp/files/* call SetStandardTabs()
augroup END
```

This configures vim to automatically figure out when you're in a subtree of /path/to/csharp/files and sets the buffer-local variables the way you want.  Put it in your .vimrc and you're good to go.

**Edit** Here's some code to put in your .vimrc that searches up the tree for the nearest "local" .vimrc and sources (loads) it.  Use with caution!  Don't set globals or do anything "interesting", you'll get hard-to-diagnose behaviors.  I have not exhaustively tested it. It might eat your children.  You have been warned!

```
" per-subtree .vimrc
function! FindAndSourceLocalVimrc()
  if exists('g:inFindLocalVimrc')
    return
  endif
  let g:inFindLocalVimrc=1

  let v = findfile('.vimrc', '.;')
  if exists('v')
    let v = fnamemodify(v, ':p')
    if v != $MYVIMRC
      exe "source " . v
    endif
  endif

  unlet g:inFindLocalVimrc
endfunction

call FindAndSourceLocalVimrc()
```

I'm sure 10 years from now I'll find some already-existing built-in way to do it in one line.

Comment: That sounds awesome, I'll give it a try.
I guess there is no chance of a local .vimrc file I can put into a project directory that then gets executed on vim start?
Would be great for putting project relevant configurations under version control with a project like that.

Comment: vim can open files in any directory after it's been started, so it wouldn't really make sense to automatically apply scripts that could potentially alter global settings.  It would be possible to modify vim so that it searches "up the directory tree" until it finds a .vimrc and applies it, but that could have security issues in addition to the globals problem.  At least the way I've outlined it here, you can have all the special cases in one place instead of scattered through the filesystem.

Comment: By modifiying Vim do you mean altering Vim's sourcecode or do you mean it could be achieved through configuration in the global .vimrc?
If Vim knows the current directory on launch, the functionality could be 'jailed' into it. I imagine this feature like the inline settings some people use in file headers, the Vim directives, but on a per-project basis.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably somewhat religious but tabs are tons easier to deal with because you can set their spacing. When someone sets spaces instead of tabs it's stuck that way and people who prefer tabs have to do all sorts of crazy conversion to get it right again.

If you want tabs to be 2 characters then in your vimrc:

```
set ts=2
set sw=2
```

Also you shouldn't need a script to do conversion. Just use `set expandtab` which does it automatically when you enter the tab character.

Comment: I know the setting for vimrc, but I need to be able to quickly switch it, I would prefer being able to switch it with a command line argument.

On the spaces/tabs religion: I usually follow the communities recommended style, in web related scripting languages (Ruby, Coffeescript, Javascript) it is always spaces, in C-style languages it is tabs afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I developed a utility in C called [`autotab`](http://www.kylheku.com/cgit/c-snippets/tree/autotab.c).  It analyzes the first several thousand lines of a text file, and then emits a Vim command to set up the `:shiftwidth`, `:expandtab` and `:tabstop` settings for that file. It is geared toward languages that look like C. `autotab` knows whether indentation is being achieved with spaces, or combinations of tabs and spaces.

The comment header in the program gives instructions for integrating it into Vim so that it is invoked automatically when you load a file.

Autotab is fast, because it's written in C, and relies only on the standard library, so it has low startup overhead, and because it limits how many lines it reads from the file. The additional latency from invoking it on every file load is hardly noticeable.